# trouble rendering SVG elements using phantomjs screen capture

Tags: javascript, svg, phantomjs

I'm using phantomjs to capture screen of my webpage. I have SVG elements on my page and **sometimes** it doesn't render those correctly.

```
var page = require('webpage').create(); 
var args = require('system').args;

var isLoad = false;

page.settings.userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90";
var w = parseFloat(args[4]);
var h = parseFloat(args[5]);
page.viewportSize = { width: w, height: h };
page.open('http://www.facegift.co.il/canvas/?userItemId=' + args[1] + '&Sc=' + args[2] + '&print=' + args[6] + '&width=' + args[4] + '&pageNum=' + args[3] + '&ver=' + args[7], function(status) { 
    var ue = page.evaluate(function(){
        return navigator.userAgent;
    });

    console.log("status: " + status);

    if(status === "success") {
       setInterval(function(){
        var ps =  page.evaluate(function() {
            document.body.bgColor = 'white';
            return document.getElementById("pageStatus").innerHTML;
        });


        if(!isLoad){
            console.log("wait...");
            if(ps == "loaded"){
              console.log("loaded");
              isLoad = true;
              page.render('example1.jpg'); 
              console.log("rendered");
              phantom.exit();
            }
        }   
    }, 100);
} 
});
```

here are examples of two results with the **same** request:

[image: good request][image: bad request]

***here is the link to the actual page I want to render:***

http://www.facegift.co.il/canvas/?userItemId=17887&sc=987404&print=1&width=4000&pageNum=7

***to call phantom I use:***

phantomjs facegift.js 17887 987404 7 4000 2048.77 1 2335

Comment: Why did you delete the exactly the [same question from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891833/trouble-rendering-svg-elements-using-phantomjs-screen-capture) and posted it again? Please don't try to game the system. We don't like reposts.

Comment: sorry, i didnt get any reply and i need a reply. what else could i do?

Comment: Since you don't have enough rep to post a bounty, there is nothing you can do. Perhaps try the PhantomJS issue tracker on github. You can also try to use another version of PhantomJS. What version are you using btw?

Comment: thanks, I've posted there as well @ArtjomB. but without any reply too. 
I use phantom ver 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

ok, fixed. the problem was in my code. 
thanks to @Paul LeBeau who answered my next related question.
[SVG disappear when zoom in on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924514/svg-disappear-when-zoom-in-on-chrome)

phantomjs and chrome are great. sorry I thought something went wrong on their behalf.