# SVG disappear when zoom in on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg

I've loaded a page with multiple SVGs on chrome. 
when I zoomin/out one of the SVG is disappearing and I have no idea why this is happening.

(and it stays like this even when I zoom back to default)

any ideas?

[image: good SVG] [image: bad SVG]

**this is the url if you want to try it yourself**

http://www.facegift.co.il/canvas/?userItemId=17887&sc=987404&print=1&width=1500&pageNum=7

Comment: Report it as a chrome bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: ive done this, thank you @RobertLongson

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a bug in Chrome. This is a bug in your page.

All the `id` attributes on the page have to be unique.  But on your page, they are not.

The `<linearGradient>` for that botanical flourish has the id `"SVGID_2_"`.  There is also a `<clipPath>` element on the page with `id="SVGID_2_"`.

Fix that problem (and any other duplicate ids) and I am certain things will start working.

Then you should also delete your Chrome bug report.

Comment: There is also a very high chance this is the cause of your phantomjs issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue in Chrome because one of the elemets had the `transform` attribute:

`transform="translate(0,-9000000000)"`

And it made Chrome go crazy. The solution was to hide or remove the element.